# Tensorflow 2.0 Saving trained parameters to be restored in a new file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to save trained variables of a TensorFlow 2.0 model using one of TF's built in functions like tf.train.Checkpoint or any other, and want to call them in a new file. I am not using tf.Keras.Sequantial and don't want to use something like model.save_weights()

I have tried tf.train.Checkpoint to save variables, but not sure how to restore them. I used to work with tf.train.Saver() in TF 1.0 to save variables using sessions and restore them using tf.train.import_meta_graph and tf.train.latest_checkpoint. However, I haven't been able to find equivalent functionalities in TF 2.0 documentation so far.

## try checkpoint saver in tensorflow 2.0 format to save trained parameters W, b_v, b_h

saver = tf.train.Checkpoint()

saver.listed = [W, b_v, b_h]

saver.mapped = {'W':saver.listed[0],'b_v':saver.listed[1],
 'b_h':saver.listed[2]}

save_path = saver.save('trained_parameters')

## in a new file:

restorer = tf.train.Checkpoint()

restorer.restore('trained_parameters')

## calling the parameters by their previously mapped names doesn't work, not sure how to go about this

Comment: Do you find a solution?